# JSch - how to use Session and UserInfo

Tags: android, jsch

When using JSch, how do I set the userinfo when I do not want to prompt the user for the password? All of the samples provided use the userinfo with Swing and prompt the user for the password at run time. I am writing an android app and I will save the password as a SharedPreference, so I will not want to prompt the user. All of the samples show them using UserInfo as a base class for their MyUserInfo class, which seems like a lot of overkill just to store a username and password.

The samples do it like this:

```
JSch jsch=new JSch();
Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
UserInfo ui=new MyUserInfo();
session.setUserInfo(ui);
session.connect();
```

and the MyUserInfo class has several methods and other things going on that I just don't need.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 4):

The [UserInfo](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/index.html?com/jcraft/jsch/UserInfo.html) object is meant just for **user interaction**. If you don't want interaction, don't use it.

While you could implement the UserInfo interface to return a static value for the password, there is an easier way: Use the [`setPassword` method on the Session](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html#setPassword%28byte%5B%5D%29) (actually, two of them: one using a String and one a byte[]), use that instead.

Comment: Is there any working example for the same without swing? any link or help would be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't use JSch for many years now, so I don't have any examples at hand. But it shouldn't be too hard to implement e.g. a console interface.